# Display images from url using json in android

Tags: android, json

I'm new in android ... so I need help. I have JSON link where I have for example like this

```
[{"id":"82","percent":"3","image_name":"something.jpg"....
```

I try some tutorial just for reading text, it was okay. But I have problem how to show in my layout the images from JSON...

Can you help or share some code about this?

Comment: could you provide some code you started writing ?

Answer (score 1):

Parse the json string : -

```
String jsonString = "your json string goes here" ;

JSONObject rootObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

String link = rootObj.getString("image_name");
```

You can now use this url/link to convert it into bitmap : -

```
Bitmap image ;    

 InputStream in = new java.net.URL(link).openStream();

   image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

    in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default you can't disaplay image using web link. However lots of libraries have been created to solve this problem. You can try [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) one. There's also a list of alternative libraries.